# Can I restore LVM PV and VG (LV) configuration to a smaller disk?

Tags: linux, restore, lvm

In a virtual machine the size of a disk was found to be too large by mistake after a VG with LV and filesystem had been put on it using all the space.
As VMware (they said to me) cannot reduce the size of a disk, the existing disk was deleted, and a new one with the correct size was created.

Now I wonder can I use LVM's backup data (`vgcfgrestore`) to restore the UUIDs of PV and VG (maybe LV, too) at least?

My first attempts to restore the VG ended up in the PV not being found, and the attempt to restore the PV first (using `pvcreate --restorefile ... -u <UUID>`) ended with an error that the new disk is too small ("**Physical extents end beyond end of device /dev/sdd**").

I'm using SLES15 SP4.

For completeness:
After restoring I'd "resize" LV, VG and PV to the proper sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cannot be done, most likely because there is no `vgresize` command (that could be used to reduce the number of extents available after the LVs' sizes had been reduced, too):

I could "restore" the PV by spcifying the previous ID:

```sh
# pvcreate -u LAWXom-t6Mq-jcqA-3Ejx-cY7D-7T1M-ae8y2E /dev/sdd
  Physical volume "/dev/sdd" successfully created.
```

Then I could restore the VG configuration (it's debatable whether that should succeed without giving a warning, or without adjusting (at least suggest to do so) the sizes):

```sh
# vgcfgrestore my-vg
  Restored volume group my-vg.
```

At that point the VG (and LV) had the size of the disk when the backup had been made.

```sh
# vgs my-vg
  WARNING: Device /dev/sdd has size of 167772160 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 314572800 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG my-vg have changed sizes.
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   Vfree
  my-vg    1   1   0 wz--n- 149.94g     0
```

So at that point (as I found no tool like `vgresize`) I had to remove and recreate the VG and LV:

```sh
# vgremove my-vg
# vgcreate -s 64M my-vg /dev/sdd
# #...lvcreate..., mkfs...
```